# The number of ways of choosing 5 cards from a standard deck of cards

Tags: combinatorics

If you  choose 5 cards from 52 cards, shouldn't the answer be 52*51*50*49*48? 
Why is the correct answer $\binom{52}{5}$? Any explanations will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please edit your question? The spelling makes it look like you put 0 effort into the question. And, a simple google search yields: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215266/what-is-the-number-of-five-card-hands-possible-from-a-standard-fifty-two-card-de?rq=1

Comment: Furthermore, looking at your old questions: please either accept an answer (check mark) if it answered your question or ask for more clarification. When someone writes and answer for you, make sure to respond (either by accepting or asking further questions)

Comment: Frin a srabdard! Frin a srabdard! AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The expression $$_{52}P_5=\frac{52!}{(52-5)!}=\frac{52!}{47!}=52\times51\times50\times49\times48$$ gives you the number of ways of selecting $5$ cards from $52$ cards provided that the ordering of the cards matters (e.g. `AKQJT` is different from `ATJKQ`).

If the order does not matter (e.g. `AKQJT` is the same as `ATJKQ`), we can further divide by the number of arrangements of $5$ objects, or $5!$, and this gives us the definition of the combination.

$$_{52}C_{5}=\binom{52}{5}=\frac{52!}{5!\ (52-5)!}=\frac{52!}{5!\ 47!}=\frac{52\times51\times50\times49\times48}{5!}$$